# Regex: How to exclude a string if it contains a specific character?

Tags: regex

I want to match any string that doesn't contain "S", if it contains it should be excluded.

**Sample:**

```
Sally Desk 
Camp Silly
Not Bad
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Desk  
Camp  
Not  
Bad
```

Comment: It should work in this tool: http://labs.odindecisions.com/Tools/RegexAnalyzer.aspx

Comment: I guess all you need is `(?m)^[^S]*$` (`(?m)` stands for multiline mode).

Comment: No it's not working. I tried ^(?!S)([A-Z][a-z]*) (?!S)([A-Z][a-z]*)$ but doesn't work aswell.

Comment: How about `\b[^S\s]+\b`?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to match any string that doesn't contain "S"

You can simply use `(?!\S*S)\b\S+\b`.This uses `lookahead` to check if `string` doesnt contain `S`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/1